# How to implement a one-to-many relationship with an "Is Current" requirement

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, database-design, relational-database

Designing a database, there's a relationship between two tables, `Job` and `Document`. One `Job` can have multiple `Documents`, but one (and only one) of these `Documents` needs to be flagged as `IsCurrent`. This is not always the most recent `Document` associated with that `Job`.

Structurally, I can see two ways of doing this.

The first is to add a `DocumentId` column to `Job`, and a `JobId` column to `Document`. This will work, but creates a circular reference: when imported into Entity Framework you end up with the peculiar situation that a `Job` has both a `Document` and a `Documents` collection. Likewise that `Document` has both a `Job` and a `Jobs` collection.

The second is to add an `IsCurrent` bit flag to the `Document` table. This will work, but leaves it logically possible for a Job to have multiple `IsCurrent` `Documents`, which is not allowed.

Questions:

1) Am I right in thinking there's no "third way" out of this dilemma?

2) Presuming not, which is better, and why? I favour the second solution as it seems much cleaner and we can enforce the single `IsCurrent` through the business logic. My colleague favours the former solution because it results in simpler C# code and object references - if we rename the foreign keys, it should avoid the confusion created by `Job/Jobs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your back-end is SQL Server, you can create a [filtered index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) to ensure that each `job` has at most one current document:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Documents_Current
    ON Documents (JobId) where IsCurrent=1
```

That way, it's not *just* enforced at the business level but is also enforced inside the database.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I thought filtered indexes were performance tools - I had no idea they could be used to enforce integrity.

Comment: @MattThrower - if you think about it, *any* unique index has at least some aspect of enforcing integrity.

Comment: so simple, so elegant... brillant and so on: always read **all** the documentation of the tools one use.

Answer (score 1):

just for a third way (and for fun): consider using not a bit, but an int equals to max + 1 among the documents of the job.

then create a unique index on {job FK, said int}.

you can:

- change current by updating the int,
- get the current by searching the max and
- prevent to have more than one current because of the unique index.
- create a new non current document by using min - 1 for said int.

this is not the simplest to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a third way out of this dilemma.  You need a DBMS that supports SQL's CREATE ASSERTION (and supports it *correctly*, of course).  With such a DBMS, you can declare any data rule that applies to your situation and your DBMS will enforce that rule for you.

Unfortunately, no such DBMS exists *** in the SQL world ***.  Outside of the SQL world, there are such engines.  ASSERTIONs being my hobbyhorse, I wrote one myself.  If you're interested, a Google search should lead you to it quickly.