# How can i map an existing foreign key to a navigation property with code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, ef-model-first

I'm using code first to create an application of customer management.
A customer can have many addresses but only one "main" address.

Here is my Customer model :

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName{ get; set; }

    public string LastName{ get; set; }

    public int MainInvoicingAddressId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MainBillingAddressId")]
    public Address MainBillingAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

And my Address Model :

```
    public class Address
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

But when i create the database, i have a auto generated foreign key Customer_Id on addresses table because of the navigation property MainBillingAddress.

So on addresses table, i have 2 foreign keys to Customer ("CustomerId" and "Customer_Id").

What i want is to use the existing foreign Key "CustomerId" for the relation with the  MainBillingAddress.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK what you want can't be done with EF. Waht you seems to want is:

1. one to one relation between Customer and Address, and
2. one to many relation between Customer and Address.

This can't be done because, with EF, 1. implies FK <=> PK. (for [example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)), that is not compatible with 2..

I humbly suggest you read [How to implement a one-to-many relationship with an "Is Current" requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624962/how-to-implement-a-one-to-many-relationship-with-an-is-current-requirement/30637439#comment49342062_30637439) and replace the "Is Current" by "Is main".

I can imagine another solution like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().
    HasOptional(x => x.MainBillingAddress). // or required
    WithMany(y => y.IsDefaultFor);
```

but this at least leads to circular refrences.